# How to create .cpython-37 file, within __pycache__

Tags: python

I'm working on a project with a few scripts in the same directory, a **pychache** folder has been created within that directory, it contains compiled versions of two of my scripts. This has happened by accident I do not know how I did it. One thing I do know is I have imported functions between the two scripts that have been compiled.

I would like a third compiled python script for a separate file however I do not want to import any modules(if this is even the case). Does anyone know how I can manually create a .cpython-37 file? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no reason to worry about `__pycache__` or `*.pyc` files - these are created and managed by the Python interpreter when it needs them and you cannot / should not worry about manually creating them. They contain a cached version of the compiled Python bytecode. Creating them manually makes no sense (and I am not aware of a way to do that), and you should probably let the interpreter decide when it makes sense to cache the bytecode and when it doesn't.

In Python 3.x, `__pycache__` directories are created for modules when they are imported by a different module. AFAIK Python will not create a `__pycache__` entry when a script is ran directly (e.g. a "main" script), only when it is imported as a module.

Comment: thanks for the response, any idea how i can create a compiled python script that runs similar to an app, i would like to avoid creating a .exe file for now thanks

Comment: You mean you want to have an "executable" Python script that users can install / run directly on a Windows desktop? This is a separate question and completely unrelated to `__pycache__` and bytecode compilation (a bytecode-compiled Python file is not an executable). I suggest you ask that in a new question.

Comment: It should be noted that it is not correct that bytecode files can not be manually created.  It can be done.  Here is a link about it:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/byte-compile-python-libraries.